# Excel #VALUE! with FILTER and IF 255 character limit

Tags: excel, filter, equation

When using below code in my equation bar I can see the filtered data from Sheet1 in Sheet2 (overview sheet). All works well, but if the character limit in i.e. Sheet1 cell C30 is >255 characters then I see #VALUE! in the Sheet2 (overview sheet). I would like to know how to ammend this so I see the full text.

I do not use VBA and I do not wish to use this. Just the simple equation box.

```
=FILTER(IF(Sheet1!A16:K332="","",Sheet1!A16:K332),(Sheet1!K16:K332="Open")+(Sheet1!K16:K332="Feedback")+(Sheet1!K16:K332="Pending"))
```

Thanks.

As above and not sure how to fix.

Comment: Try Removing the IF and use: `=FILTER(Sheet1!A16:K332,(Sheet1!K16:K332="Open")+(Sheet1!K16:K332="Feedback")+(Sheet1!K16:K332="Pending"))&""`

Comment: Thanks, this indeed worked, but the dates are showing 49102 etc. I tried with formatting and no formatting to both sheets but made no difference. Seems the equation above works but has issues with date. I put ' in front of the dates in Sheet1 and it works.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: The IF is what is causing the issue.  If you do not mind `0` in the fields where they were blank then remove the `&""` which turns everything into a string.  Or do the columns separately so that numbers and dates are treated differently than strings.  It is one of the draw backs of formula.